# Prove that this graph can be divided to 3 clusters

Tags: graph-theory

Assume in a graph with 36 vertices degree of each vertex is at least 34. Prove that this graph's vertices can be divided info 3 clusters(complete sub-graphs) each with 12 vertices.
Any hints how to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a complement graph. It does not have vertices of degree more than 1. Thus it have no more than 18 edges. Let's write them in pairs, each two connected vertices in pair, 18 pairs total (let's enumerate pairs as $1-18$, with top($t$) and bottom($b$) vertices in each pair). It's clear that vertices can be in same cluster of main graph iff they are in different pairs in complement graph.
Take this division: $(1t, ..., 6t, 7b, ..., 12b), (7t, ..., 12t, 13b, ..., 18b), (13t, ..., 18t, 1b, ..., 6b)$

It gives us give three complete subgraphs.